# Compute average over sliding time interval (7 days ago/later) in R

Tags: r

I've seen a lot of solutions to working with groups of times or date, like `aggregate` to sum daily observations into weekly observations, or other solutions to compute a moving average, but I haven't found a way do what I want, which is to pluck relative dates out of data keyed by an additional variable.

I have daily sales data for a bunch of stores. So that is a data.frame with columns

```
store_id date sales
```

It's nearly complete, but there are some missing data points, and those missing data points are having a strong effect on our models (I suspect). So I used `expand.grid` to make sure we have a row for every store and every date, but at this point the sales data for those missing data points are NAs. I've found solutions like

```
dframe[is.na(dframe)] <- 0
```

or

```
dframe$sales[is.na(dframe$sales)] <- mean(dframe$sales, na.rm = TRUE)
```

but I'm not happy with the RHS of either of those. I want to replace missing sales data with our best estimate, and the best estimate of sales for a given store on a given date is the average of the sales 7 days prior and 7 days later. E.g. for Sunday the 8th, the average of Sunday the 1st and Sunday the 15th, because sales is significantly dependent on day of the week.

So I guess I can use

```
dframe$sales[is.na(dframe$sales)] <- my_func(dframe)
```

where my_func(dframe) replaces every stores' sales data with the average of the store's sales 7 days prior and 7 days later (ignoring for the first go around the situation where one of *those* data points is also missing), but I have no idea how to write `my_func` in an efficient way.

How do I match up the store_id and the dates 7 days prior and future without using a terribly inefficient for loop? Preferably using only base R packages.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
with(
  dframe, 
    ave(sales, store_id, FUN=function(x) {
      naw <- which(is.na(x))
      x[naw] <- rowMeans(cbind(x[naw+7],x[naw-7]))
      x
    }
  )
)
```

Comment: Nope. `dframe$sales[naw+7]` is not necessarily (or even likely) sales from the same store_id 7 days later.

Comment: @OldPro - wrapping the code in `ave` should do it. See my edits.

Comment: That sort of works if I sort the data frame by date first. I get back a vector though. And why `rowMeans(cbind(x[naw+7],x[naw-7]))` instead of `(x[naw+7] + x[naw-7])/2`?

Comment: @OldPro - yep, it'll need to be sorted by store_id and date, but that will be the case for any solution really. You get back a vector for `dframe$sales` with the NA values replaced. I believe that's what you requested. As to why I used `rowMeans(cbind...` - I dunno, it's what came to me first.